# 404 Not Found nginx on wp-admin

Tags: 404-error, nginx

I have my own domain and I'm hosting the site on InfinityFree. So when typing **http:// mysite.com/wp-admin** it gives me 404 Not Found-nginx page.

I have installed WordPress successfully and also added a nameserver. I have changed nothing, just installed fresh and end up with this.

I don't know what wrong? I'm creating the site for myself and still learning. I've read few articles but did not found the exact answer.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try httpS:// mysite.com/wp-admin

If not then check with your hosting company if they are able to fix the issue. It could happen due to SSL (https redirects) or 301 redirects.